# java regexp get more than need

Tags: java, regex

I have following regexp

```
http://[a-z./].*(js)
```

and the string

```
efwefewfhttp://assets.main.com/zepto-1.1.3.min.js fffhttp://assets.main.com/zepto-1.1.3.min.js
```

Code:

```
List<String> kk = new ArrayList<String>();

while (urlMatcher.find()){
    kk.add(urlMatcher.group());
}
```

This regexp output is

```
http://assets.main.com/zepto-1.1.3.min.js fffhttp://assets.main.com/zepto-1.1.3.min.js
```

but should be 2 strings in result

How change regexp to get two string as result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex with lazy dot matching pattern:

```
http://[a-z./].*?js
                ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE0gB2/2)

With this, you will match `http://assets.main.com/zepto-1.1.3.min.js` and `http://assets.main.com/zepto-1.1.3.min.js`.

The thing is that `.*` matches the whole line and then backtracks, checking if it can accommodate for the right-hand pattern. Thus it matches the longest possible substring (from the left-most up to the right-most). Lazy matching will match from the left-most to the first occurrence of the next subpattern yielding 2 matches.

See [*Watch Out for The Greediness!*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) section.

Also, since these are links, and there should be no spaces, you can use `\S` (non-whitespace) shorthand char class:

```
http://[a-z./]\S*\.js
```

Also, the literal dot can be matched with `\.`. See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE0gB2/3).

*Lazy/greedy dot matching should be avoided as often as possible due to heavy backtracking they might involve!*

[Sample code](http://ideone.com/mGDMin):

```
String str = "efwefewfhttp://assets.main.com/zepto-1.1.3.min.js fffhttp://assets.main.com/zepto-1.1.3.min.js";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("http://[a-z./]\\S*\\.js");
Matcher urlMatcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
List<String> kk = new ArrayList<String>();
while (urlMatcher.find()){
    kk.add(urlMatcher.group());
}
System.out.println(kk);
// [http://assets.main.com/zepto-1.1.3.min.js, http://assets.main.com/zepto-1.1.3.min.js]
```